# Why Array in EJS template is displaying long list of letters instead of the complete result?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I want to display array results from my MongoDB but I'm having a problem displaying them on the frontend using the EJS template.

This is the code I used to query my result:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {



    user.find({}, {twitter: 0, __v: 0, _id: 0}, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err; 

        //console.log(result); 

result.forEach(function(u) {
        u=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(u))

 results = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(u.meme.imgs)) 

        console.log(results);

     return res.render('pages/index', {

            path: results,
            state: req.session.state


        });   

});  



    });


});
```

The `console.log` is displaying the array results for me completely but by the time I want to display on the frontend using EJS it is giving me this unnecessary list of letters.

This is the result the array is returning:

```
"
h
t
t
p
:
/
/
l
o
c
a
l
h
o
s
t
/
p
u
b
l
i
c
/
I
m
a
g
e
s
/
o
k
r
o
.
j
p
g
"
```

This is the code for displaying the result on the frontend:

```
<ul>
    <% for(var i=0; i<path.length; i++) { %>
        <li>

<%- path[i] %> 
        </li>
    <% } %>
</ul>
```

What am I doing wrong? please help.

Comment: You can make this a whole answer instead of just a comment. To make things clearer. Thanks.

Comment: you are right, done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks that you are missing the declaration of results, this makes results variable to be global variable, and its value can be unpredictable, because it may be changed by anyone, seems the results sent to client is string, and you iterate over the characters of the string and print it. Try to add let to results declaration.

```
let results = ...
```

Also strinigfy u and then parse it, as done in two places in you'r example:

```
u=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(u)) 
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(u.meme.imgs))
```

will return the same object, it has no effect doing so, just makes the code confusing and less readable.